# Passing a variable to an ImageJ MIJI command from MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, imagej

I'm trying to use the MATLAB ImageJ interface (Miji) to run a block of commands, but am having difficulty passing variables into the options for a macro command. I am attempting to load in a .tif stack of images and split them up into smaller stacks by using ImageJ's duplicate command.

From the ImageJ website for the macro builder, it states;

> pass variables to commands called using run() by adding "&" variable names.

For example

```
values = 1-5
run("Duplicate...","duplicate range=&values")
```

This should duplicate an image stack within the range set by values. However when translating this to MATLABs MIJI plugin as follows;

```
MIJ.run('Duplicate...','duplicate range=&values')
```

This doesn't work and only duplicates the full image stack. Breaking the string ' ' throws an unexpected MATLAB operator error.

I have attempted storing the range values as string text as well as in a matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this by using `sprintf`

```
values = 1-5;
MIJ.run('Duplicate...',sprintf('duplicate range=%d',values));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try concatenating your strings using one of [MATLAB's supported string concatenation techniques](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html). Maybe easiest is to use the square brackets, like so:

```matlab
MIJ.run('Duplicate...', ['duplicate range=' values])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I was actually able to fix my issue by using `sprintf`. I will write up an answer soon.